# Optimizing a PostgreSQL SELECT query (sqlfiddle)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sqlfiddle

I have 2 tables named `player` and `team`, which are tied together in a many-to-many relationship via a third table named `player_team`.

The table structure & current query can be found: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6db4/18

I need a query, that returns the player's data, along with `team.id`, which includes the player's maximum rating. Also, if the rating is `<= X`, then that player should be excluded.

The example query returns the correct results, but is quite inefficient.

Obviously, the same results can be achieved by accessing each table's rows only once, but the question is how to achieve this? (I'd prefer replies that are in PostgreSQL dialect)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that you could try:

```
with all_comb as (
select p.id as PLID,
       t.id as TID,
       t.rating as RATING
  from player p,
       team t,
       player_team pt
 where p.id = pt.pid
   and t.id = pt.tid
   and t.rating >0)

select distinct
       a.PLID,
       a.TID,
       a.RATING
  from all_comb a
 where a.RATING = (
       select max(b.RATING)
         from all_comb b
        where a.PLID = b.PLID)
 order by PLID;
```

The sqlfiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e6db4/10).